# array of std::bitset as a return value

Tags: c++, bitset

I need to write a function to do N different Boolean operators on two std::bitset which in each run program can have different size. so I tried to write a function that do the operation inside and return array of bitset but I don't know how should I define return value?

```
template<size_t SIZE>
    ....  bitwiseOperator(bitset<SIZE> r_1, bitset<SIZE> r_2, vector<int> fun)
    {
      int  k = 0;
      bitset<SIZE> r_12;
      const int N =   fun.size();
      bitset<SIZE> rs[N];
      for(vector<int>::iterator it = fun.begin(); it != fun.end(); ++it) 
      {
        if (*it == 1)         
        {
                r_12 = r_1 & r_2;
        }
        else if(*it == 2)  
        {
                r_12 = r_1 | r_2;
        }
        else if(*it == 3) 
        {
                r_12 = r_1 ^ r_2;
        }
        rs[k] = r_12;
        k++;
     }
        return rs;
    }
```

I need return value to be something like bitset[N]

Comment: What about providing an output iterator

Comment: [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: `sizeof(fun)` is probably a mistake. Did you mean `fun.size()` ? (the number of elements in the vector)

Comment: @Pradhan the problem is that I don't know the size of return array and need to calculate it based on size of fun. and I want avoid using vector.

Comment: Is it necessary to copy the entire vector just to read its values?

Comment: @NeilKirk I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: You pass the vector by value which means it is copied. Pass by const reference instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you want to return a variable sized array suggests using a `std::vector`.

**So I would probably do this:**

```
template<size_t SIZE>
std::vector<std::bitset<SIZE> > bitwiseOperator(bitset<SIZE> r_1,
    bitset<SIZE> r_2, vector<int> fun)
{
    int k = 0;
    bitset<SIZE> r_12;

    const int N = fun.size(); // not sizeof(fun); !!!

    std::vector<std::bitset<SIZE> > rs(N); // Variable size suggests std::vector

    for(vector<int>::iterator it = fun.begin(); it != fun.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it == 1)
        {
            r_12 = r_1 & r_2;
        }
        else if(*it == 2)
        {
            r_12 = r_1 | r_2;
        }
        else if(*it == 3)
        {
            r_12 = r_1 ^ r_2;
        }
        rs[k] = r_12;
        k++;
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying, yet my concern is performance here otherwise I have already implemented the code in numpy and working fine (except its performance). So here I really want to avoid using vector

Comment: I recommend you do some testing because I doubt the vector will be any slower than a raw array. A vector is a raw array under the hood and the function calls will likely be optimized away.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA firstly you don't have much choice: arrays cannot be returned by value in C++, and arrays must have size known at compile-time.  Secondly don't jump to conclusions about performance.

Comment: Ok then I will go with vector solution, Thanks

Comment: If the function is to be called many times though, perhaps you could pass a vector as an "out - byref" parameter so it does not continaully allocate and deallocate each call